# Discuss the convergence of the series $\sum_{n}^{\infty}\left( e^{-2n}-e^{-2(n+1)} \right)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Discuss the convergence of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=}^{\infty}\left( e^{-2n}-e^{-2(n+1)} \right)$$

**Answer:**

Let $ S_m $ be the partial sums of $ m \ $ terms .

Then ,

$S_m=(e^{-2}-e^{-4})+(e^{-4}-e^{-6})+.......+ (e^{-2m}-e^{-2(m+1)} ) \\ \Rightarrow S_m=(e^{-2}-e^{-2(m+1)} ) $

Taking limit , we get

$ \lim_{m \to \infty} S_m=e^{-2}-0=\frac{1}{e^2} \ $

Thus the sequence of partial sum converges to the limit $ \large \frac{1}{e^2} \ $

Hence the series converges.

**Am I right ?**

**If not , any help ?**

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Series of this kind, that is, a series of the form $\sum a_n$ where $a_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$ are called *telescoping series*.

Comment: As already said, you are correct. May be, it could have been faster to write $$S_m= \sum_{n=1}^{p} \left( e^{-2n}-e^{-2(n+1)} \right) = \left(1-\frac 1{e^2}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{p}  e^{-2n}=\frac{1-e^{-2 p}}{e^2}$$ which shows the limit and how it is approched.